# Facebook Android SDK requires API 15: Android 4.0.3 or higher. Should I use tools:override to force usage?

Tags: java, android, facebook, gradle, facebook-android-sdk

I would rather not upgrade my Android min API level as some users are still on API 14. However Facebook requires that I upgrade to API 15 to integrate the Facebook Android SDK. Are there any advantages/disadvatages to  using tools:overrideLibrary=“com.facebook” to force usage in my gradle build? What be the best practice to integrate the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of users between API 14 and 15 is VERY small. If you take a look at the Android dashboard statistics, it's almost none.

[image]

According to Android Studio, it doesn't even equal to 0.1% of users.

[image]

[image]

They both end up at 97.4%.

For something that small, I wouldn't recommend changing lib and I would say you should change your mininum API.

If a user using API 14 and they don't have facebook, they won't care abou this at all.

Just my opinion.

Comment: Bear in mind that those statistics are only US, but the _rest of the world_ has a different agenda (in fact, I've seen people using 2.2 in South America like it was hot candy). Maybe that's exaggerating, but just saying that if you want to target a "world wide" market, you have to be careful. I personally try to target 17+ (soon 19). I found out that the time/money needed to maintain old versions is not worth. Yes, "it just works with the support libs" but there are far more problems "outside" the frameworks. Crappy devices, rooted, etc.